# How can I drag a DOM object(image) (which is outside of ) into a map then create a marker there?

Tags: google-maps, drag-and-drop, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I just want to add some kind of markers which are listed beside map, then user can drag them in to map. I tried to use GEvent.addDomListener(domObj, "drag",functName); but it didn't works. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks
Dau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or not, but I would recommend using this library as it will streamline the process of creating the draggable DOM element and finding the position for the element.

This example relies on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to find the Div Pixel coordinates of draggable element after it has been moved.

Using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) - we are going to do a couple of things:

- Make the Element Draggable
- Create an event listener for when the dragging of an element has stopped
- Pass the position of the element once the element has moved to another function called 'createMarker' where we will create our marker

  ```
   $("#dragMe").draggable({
       stop:function(event,ui){
            window.createMarker(ui.position);
       }
   });
  ```

Create Marker will be responsible for doing a few things:

- Receive the Left and Top position of our draggable element
- Calculate the equivalent GLatLng point for that point while taking the offset of our map into consideration
- Create the marker and add it to the map

  ```
          function createMarker(position)
          {
              //Adjust Offset
              var offset = {
                      left:10,
                      top:-5
              }

                 //Create a new GPoint
                 var myGPoint = new GPoint(
                     position.left+offset.left,
                     position.top+offset.top
                 );

                 //Calculate the LatLng for this point
                 var myLatLng = map.fromDivPixelToLatLng(myGPoint);

                 //Create the Marker and add it to the Map
                 var marker = new GMarker(myLatLng);
                 map.addOverlay(marker);
              }
  ```

I also created a working example of this code [located here](http://johnmick.net/drag-dom-make-marker/).  Be sure and let me know if you have any other questions, I hope this helps!

:)

Comment: +1... Good answer. I was planning to answer this question, but I'm sure I wouldn't have done better :)

Comment: Nice Answer.. But I do I do this? "Calculate the equivalent GLatLng point for that point while taking the offset of our map into consideration"  in map API 3